# How to add in session in the javascript code?

Tags: c#, javascript, session, authentication

[image]

Before I add in this part of session code, it will redirect me to BlogEntry.aspx if my username and password is correct. After I add in the session code, when I clicked the button nothing happening. Can you help me convert my session code to work in the javascript? I need to code it in the javascript and not in the code behind because I am using a html button. Because I want the design of the button, I need to do this. Unless you tell me there's a way to do it in the code behind. After login in login.aspx. It will redirect to logined.aspx and display welcome admin in the label.

**Login.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/loginstyle.css" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[




        function Button1_onclick() {

            if (document.getElementById('txtUserName').value == "Admin" && document.getElementById('txtPassword').value == "123") {

                //After add in session it cannot redirect    START HERE
                Session.Add("Username", txtUserName.Value);
                Session.Add("Password", txtPassword.Value);
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Value, true);                       
                window.location.assign("BlogEntry.aspx")
                //After add in session it cannot redirect    END HERE

            }
            else 
            {
                document.getElementById("<%=lblError.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "Name can't be blank!";
            }           
        }

// ]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="" method="post">

        <div class="header">
        <h1>Login Form</h1>
        <span>Fill out the form below to login to my super awesome imaginary control panel.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
        <input name="username" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="Username" runat="server" id="txtUserName" />
        <div class="user-icon"></div>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="Password" runat="server" id="txtPassword" />
        <div class="pass-icon"></div>       
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Login" class="button" runat="server" id="Button1" önserverclick="Button1_Click"  onclick="return Button1_onclick()" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
<div class="gradient"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Logined.aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Logout.Visible = false;
    string memName = (String)Session["UserName"];
    lblUsername.Text = String.Concat("Welcome Guest!");

    if (Session["Username"] != null && Session["Username"] != String.Empty)
    {
        lblUsername.Text = "Welcome, " + memName + "!";


    }
}
```

**For  @Sangram**

[image]

Comment: Ouch! Never compare stuff like login information in javascript!

Comment: It';s for a school project. It's ok. Then what should i do? @Sandman

Comment: Nope, always let the server compare login information and redirect to the correct page.

Comment: But how to do it in the code behind if i am using html button? @Daan Olislagers

Comment: `var UserID = '<%= Session["userid"] %>'` should set a js variable from Session. remove 'Winforms' label

Comment: Where to put that code? @Sangram

Comment: @Jordjmax: Use this code inside `<script language='javascript'> var UserID = '<%= Session["userid"] %>'</script>` on a page where you would like retrieve any session value.

Comment: @Sangram Then how about storing the session? for my login.aspx. U said retrieve session id, that means it is for Logined.aspx?

Comment: If you want to store it in Session using codebehind, its easy. use `Session["username"] = txtUserName.text`. If you want to store in session using Js.Jquery then you will need to call a codebehind function using JSON call

Comment: Thought that I said that the html button cannot generate a code behind @Sangram

Comment: Like i said, For that you need create a function in codebehind. You can call this function using jquery JSON call. This is possible on html button click. This is a simple example how can you do it. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Make-AJAX-Call-to-ASP.Net-Server-Side-Web-service-method-using-jQuery.aspx

Comment: @Jordjmax: could you solve your issue?

Comment: I downloaded the example that u have gave me. Ok good it generates a code behind for the html button. But when i Want to code it as normal, I have error. I wan to code it like how i code for my asp button. I show you two example in the image, one with error which is html button that the example given. And another is I add a asp button to show u that I want to code it like how I code it normally. @Sangram

Comment: You cannot access `txtusername` inside a static function. Write another non static function and call it from there to Set whatever you would like call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html session storage or localStorage to store your key values. this will not need any server side code. The info will be there even if the user close the browser.

for browser compatibility: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

for example: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Comment: Ok saw both website. Still don't know how to put to my code. @AkshyaDash